# File upload in ASP.NET Core 2 razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to do a simple file upload in asp.net core 2 razor pages.  I have the code below.  Please realize that it is imcomplete.  When i run in my VS2017, I check my FileUpload object, and it is unfortunately null.  I would hope that it is something besides null and I could create a stream to get some data out of it.  However, with the object being null, I would suspect that I do not have something tied together correctly.  Any thoughts are appreciated.  Thanks.

Code behind cs:

```
public class PicturesModel : PageModel
{
    public PicturesModel()
    {

    }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Picture")]
    [BindProperty]
    public IFormFile FileUpload { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {

    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        //FileUpload is null
        return RedirectToPage("/Account/Pictures");
    }
}
```

front end cshtml file;

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label asp-for="FileUpload"></label>
    <input type="file" asp-for="FileUpload" id="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your property for the file input is named `FileUpload` but you have overridden the `name` attribute generated by the TagHelper and renamed it to `file` which does not match the property name.

Change the view code to

```
<input type="file" asp-for="FileUpload" />
```

so that it generates the correct `name` attribute (which is `name="FileUpload"`). Note also the removal of `id="file"` which means that you `<label>` would not have set focus to the associated control when clicked).

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  The overriding the name attribute seems to have caused the issue.  I have taken that out, and now the FileUpload object is coming through with what appears to be the correct value.  Much appreciated.
 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I spent ages trying all kinds of solutions this morning, and none seemed to work.  But eventually, I came up with this...  Enjoy.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Upload a .pdf file for a particular [User] record
    /// </summary>
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("uploadPDF/{UserId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> uploadPDF(string UserId, IFormFile inputFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserId))
                throw new Exception("uploadPDF service was called with a blank ID.");
            Guid id;
            if (!Guid.TryParse(RequestId, out id))
                throw new Exception("uploadPDF service was called with a non-GUID ID.");

            var UserRecord = dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(s => s.UserID == id);
            if (UserRecord == null)
                throw new Exception("User record not found.");

            var UploadedFileSize = Request.ContentLength;
            if (UploadedFileSize == 0)
                throw new Exception("No binary data received.");

            var values = Request.ReadFormAsync();
            IFormFileCollection files = values.Result.Files;
            if (files.Count == 0)
                throw new Exception("No files were read in.");

            IFormFile file = files.First();
            using (Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
                byte[] bytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)UploadedFileSize);

                Trace.WriteLine("Saving PDF file data to database..");
                UserRecord.RawData = bytes;
                UserRecord.UpdatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                dbContextWebMgt.SaveChanges();
            }

            return new OkResult();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex, "uploadPDF failed");
            return new BadRequestResult();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no files parameter in Post method.

Check tutorial here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  :-)