# Is there any way to get full path of file in form?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to get file by input element of type "file". That element is in partial view and I want to send it to controller or request it there by "Request.Form["inputFile"];". This way give me only name of the file. In the controller i want to send it via email attachment but I need to load that file.

Aplication is **ASP.NETCore Razor** Pages and elements like Request.Files[] are not there.

Does anyone has some idea to achieve this?

Comment: The inputFile is not part of your Page Model?\

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384127/file-upload-in-asp-net-core-2-razor-pages this might help you

Comment: My model in partialView where input element is does not contain IFormFile. I can't bind it this way. My question still remains if there is another way to achieve this, or just this one throug editing partialView model?

Comment: For RazorPages, I am not sure if there is a different way than having File part of the PageModel. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This way give me only name of the file. In the controller i want to send it via email attachment but I need to load that file.

It seems that you'd like to enable browser user to upload file(s) through form's file input field. Please note that the file location on the client's machine is not accessible from web server, if you want to send user selected file as email attachment, you can save the uploaded file on your web server or other storage service etc first, then access the stored file and send it via email attachment in your code logic.

And this doc is about "Upload files in ASP.NET Core", you can refer to it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0